# Is there an ease on the 4 color theorem when the map is triangulated?

Tags: algorithm, graph, 3d, graph-algorithm

Is there an ease on the 4 color problem when the map is triangulated?

For debugging purpose, I want to colorize the triangles of the surface of a convex 3D-polyhedron with as few colors as possible (so that I have a lot of clearly distinguishable colors in reserve for coloring triangles of special interest).

4 color theorem states that 4 colors are sufficient to do that, but I hope that with the additional condition that the surface is triangulated there would be easier and more efficient algorithms than for the general case.

Further, in my few scratch examples, I always can do with 3 colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider the tetrahedron, there is no way to color its faces/triangles with just 3 colors. Therefore, it is not true that the faces of a triangulated convex polytope of dimension 3 can be colored with 3 colors. But it happens to be the only counterexample!

In fact, the graph you are trying to color is **cubic** (put a vertex in each face, and connect it to the three adjacent faces), i.e. every vertex has degree 3, and it is also **connected**. Thus, by [Brooks' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem), every cubic connected graph different of *K_4* can be colored with at most 3 colors.

EDIT:

I did not notice in my first reading that you were also looking for an algorithm. The proof I know of Brooks' theorem is constructive and hence we have an algorithm for your problem.

Using [Steinitz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz%27s_theorem) on the dual graph of the polytope we obtain that the graph we want to color is always 3-connected. This is not really needed, as the proof works for the other case, but this is the simpler case, so let me stick to the 3-connected case as it is your case.

Take any three vertices *v_1*, *v_2*, *v_n* such that *v_n* is adjacent to the other two, but *v_1* and *v_2* are non-adjacent (for the complete graph such triplet does not exist). Using that the graph is 3-connected, it is clear that if we remove *v_1* and *v_2* the resulting graph is still connected.

Arrange the remaining vertices in a sequence *v_3*, *v_4*, ..., *v_n*, such that for every *v_i* there exists *j* > *i* such that *v_i* and *v_j* are adjacent (this is like constructing a spanning tree as in Prim's algorithm starting at *v_n*). Place *v_1*, *v_2* at the beginning of the sequence, thus obtaining *v_1*, *v_2*, *v_3*, ..., *v_n*.

Use color 1 for *v_1* and *v_2* (this is valid as they are non-adjacent). Now color greedily the rest of the sequence in order, i.e. assign to each vertex the first valid color (the first not assigned to an already colored neighbor). For every vertex other than *v_n* we have a "right neighbor", so no more than 3 colors are used. For *v_n* it also works because *v_1* and *v_2* have both color 1. Now we have a 3-coloring of the graph and the algorithm is linear in the size of the graph.

Comment: Thanks, I now have code for this that does not crash and returns sane results on my few examples at least. Curiously, I observe that in most examples the third color is needed for only a few triangles. Now I wonder if the need for the third color is indicative of something, some property of the mesh? (Technically, the rarity of the third color is obviously a result of a smoothing algorithm, dividing each triangle into 6 new ones)